# Powershell - Combining Variables Properties from AD output

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting, popup, output

First script I have tried to put together. Im trying to get a new variable with ad user name and ad computer by comparing user name property and description properties. I don't know how to pull the properties I want into the new variables based on a compare-object or match. The description property has a setup of username - ######## numbers very.
Variables used (date tell expire)
$**SevenDayWarnDate**, $**ThreeDayWarnDate**, $**OneDayWarnDate**
AD user
$**7**, $**3**, $**1** -properties "Name", "PasswordExpiry
AD computer
$**comp**  "Name", "Description"
I was then going to make a pop up on user computer based on expiring passwords.
Below is what I was trying to do but im not sure if the needed information was passed as computer filed comes back empty.

```
$SevenDayWarnDate = (get-date).adddays(7).ToLongDateString()

$7= Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0 } `
 -Properties "Name", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select-Object -Property "Name", `
 @{Name = "PasswordExpiry"; Expression = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed").tolongdatestring() }} `
 |Where-object -Property PasswordExpiry -EQ $SevenDayWarnDate

$comp = Get-Adcomputer -Filter {Enabled -eq $True}  -SearchBase "OU=,DC=" -properties "Name", "Description" `
| Select-Object -Property "Name", "Description"
```

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $7 -DifferenceObject $comp -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru |
 ForEach-Object {
  [PSCustomObject]@{
  Name = $_.name
  Computer = ($comp.name | Where-Object Description -match $_.name).Directory
  }
}
```

Working code based on Santiago Squarzon below.

```
$dayArray= @()
$dayArray=@(7,3,1)

foreach ($day in $dayArray)
{
$SevenDayWarnDate = (get-date).adddays($day).ToLongDateString()
$filter = "Enabled -eq '$True' -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq '$False' -and PasswordLastSet -gt '0'"

$computerArray= @()
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties "Name", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object Name, @{
            Name = "PasswordExpiry"
            Expression = 
            {
                    [datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed").tolongdatestring()
                }
    } | Where-object -Property PasswordExpiry -EQ $SevenDayWarnDate

# => It might be better to use:
#    PasswordExpiry -ge [datetime]::Now -and PasswordExpiry -le $sevenDayWarnDate

# Find the computers each user is using
$result = foreach($user in $users)
    {
            $temp=$user.Name
            if ($comp = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Description -like '*$temp*'" -Properties Description)
                { 
                

                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Name = $user.Name
                        PasswordExpiry = $user.PasswordExpiry
                        ComputerName = $comp.Name
                        ComputerDescription = $comp.Description
                }

                $tmpArray= @()
                $tmpArray= $comp.Name.Split(" ")
                foreach($item in $tmparray)
                    {
                        $computerArray += $item
                    }
                $tmpArray = $Null
                #   }

                }
        continue
        }

foreach($computer in $computerArray) 

$tmpMessage = 
$tmpMessageTitle =

    {Send-RDUserMessage -HostServer $env:COMPUTERNAME -UnifiedSessionID 1 -MessageTitle $tmpMessageTitle -MessageBody $tmpMessage

    }


$result | Format-Table
}
```

Comment: Posted more of the code. I am trying to compare name filed in one variable to the description filed on the other. Take the equal objects and take different fields one with user name one with computer name. Then i was planing on sending a message to the users i was looking at using  (" Send-RDUserMessage -HostServer "computer" -UnifiedSessionID 1 -MessageTitle "Message from Administrator" -MessageBody "Test 1") Sorry sense this is the first time im really useing powershell for more then basic information gathering I might have a hard time explaining.

Comment: So you're looking to join the `$user` array with the `$computer`. The `Description` property of `$computer` has the username or how can you tell which computer belongs to which user?

Comment: Correct, from the sounds of it. So im trying to match the user with password expiring in seven days with there computer name.

Comment: I was at one point trying to remove the -##### out of the description but with no luck. That would let me then just flip the $7 and $comp I think might fix the issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure you want this: `PasswordExpiry -EQ $SevenDayWarnDate` ? It means you will only find users that have that exact date, wouldn't it make more sense to use a range? ie: _from this date to `$SevenDayWarnDate`_

Comment: I have one setup for 7 3 and1  just wanted to post a basic code so its easy to read. If I can get one working I can get the others but also it would be nice to make the code more formatted but I would have to ask for more help to compact it so I just went with the basic issue.

Comment: Never compare datetime objects by first stringifying them. Treat these as **objects**,  skip the time part on `$SevenDayWarnDate` by using `$SevenDayWarnDate = (get-date).adddays(7).Date`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and the code in question, I'm guessing this is what you're looking for. There is no need to use `Compare-Object`, you can simply query Active Directory to get the user's computer based on the `Description` property.

```
$SevenDayWarnDate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(7)
$filter = "Enabled -eq '$True' -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq '$False' -and PasswordLastSet -gt '0'"


$users = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties "Name", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object Name, @{
    Name = "PasswordExpiry"
    Expression = {
        [datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")
    }
} | Where-object -Property PasswordExpiry -EQ $SevenDayWarnDate
# => It might be better to use:
#    {$_.PasswordExpiry -ge [datetime]::Now -and $_.PasswordExpiry -le $sevenDayWarnDate}

# Find the computers each user is using
$result = foreach($user in $users)
{
    if($comp = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(description=$($user.Name))" -Properties Description)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $user.Name
            PasswordExpiry = $user.PasswordExpiry
            ComputerName = $comp.Name
            ComputerDescription = $comp.Description
        }
        
        continue
    }

    Write-Host "No computer was found for User: $($user.Name)"
}

$result | Format-Table
```

Comment: Im trying to run the script and break down what it is all doing. when the below part runs $users stays empty when i check the $users. br/ Test

Comment: @Shawn right, that's why I told you in my comment that `-EQ` is not the best way to compare this, you should be using a range between one that and another date. => `PasswordExpiry -EQ $SevenDayWarnDate` should be changed for something else.

Comment: But there are seven people with that expire date that should be placed there. I tried the other one but am getting an error: Where-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:11 char:5
+ } | Where-object -Property PasswordExpiry -ge [datetime]::Now -and Pa ...
sense im new it might be im doing something wrong on my side ill keep looking and breaking down the code.

Comment: I think i might have figured it out. $user has the month as the number where 1/13/2022 3:29:27 PM  where $SevenDayWarnDate comes up Friday, December 24, 2021 7:31:22 PM i just got to figure out date format.

Comment: @Shawn you would need to use scriptblock if you wanted to test that, see me edit.

Comment: @ Santiago Squarzon I was able to get a working code using yours as the base. Thank you for all the help.